# AngularJs decoupling page segments' nav links but maintaining one navigation system

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**I have a side menu directive that populates itself from a Sidebar Controller but the routing for all click events on the entire website comes from the page's parent Route Controller.**

**The Container main page**

```
<body data-ng-controller ="RouteCtrl as vm">       
    <div data-header=""></div> 
    <div data-ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">            
        <div data-side-bar=""></div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
 ......
 </body>
```

**The SidebarCtrl**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'SidebarCtrl';

angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', SidebarCtrl]);

function SidebarCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'SidebarCtrl';

    vm.toggleMenu = function () {
        vm.minifyMe = !vm.minifyMe;
    };

    vm.expandNav = function (item) {
        if (item !== vm.expandedItem) {
            vm.expandedItem = item;
        } else {
            //vm.expandedItem = null;
        }
    };

    vm.menuItems = [
        {
            name: "Parent", subMenu:
                [
                    { name: "Sub 1", module: "Mod1", url: "rootPage" },
                    { name: "Sub 2", module: "Mod2", url: "mod2Sub1/somePage" },
                    { name: "Sub 3", module: "Mod3", url: "folder2/mod3Sub2/somePage" },
                    { name: "Sub 4", module: "Mod4", url: "folder3/subFoler/somePage" }
                ]
        }

    ];
}
angular.module('app')
    .directive('sideBar', function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/app/html/common/sidebar.html'
        };
    });

})();
```

**The sidebar html**

```
<aside id="left-panel" data-ng-controller="SidebarCtrl as vm">
     ....
            <li data-ng-repeat="menuItem in vm.menuItems"  ....>
                    <span class="menu-item-parent">{{menuItem.name}}</span>
              <ul ....>
                <li data-ng-repeat="subItem in menuItem.subMenu">
                     <a style="cursor: pointer;" data-ng-click="vm.changeView('{{subItem.module}}','{{subItem.url}}')">{{subItem.name}}</a>
                 </li>
            </ul>                
          </li>  
     ....
  </aside>
```

**The Route Controller**

```
    // Route navigation for entire app
    vm.changeView = function (moduleView, dashboardView) {
        $rootScope.event = { viewUrl: dashboardView, moduleUrl: moduleView };
        console.log(dashboardView);
        $location.path(dashboardView); 
    };

    var newRoute = $routeParams.primaryNav;

    if ($routeParams.secondaryNav != "" && $routeParams.secondaryNav != undefined) {
        newRoute = newRoute + '/' + $routeParams.secondaryNav;
    }

    if ($routeParams.tertiaryNav != "" && $routeParams.tertiaryNav != undefined) {
        newRoute = newRoute + '/' + $routeParams.tertiaryNav;
    }

    $scope.templateUrl = '/app/html/' + newRoute + '.html';
```

1. As show above, the side bar populates but the routing does not work
2. If I made the sidebar nav static [which I do not want], and the sidebar page's controller the RouteCtrl the side bar navigation responds properly.

How can I maintain the entire navigation of the website in the route controller, yet decouple the various segments of the website, eg. the sidebar nav, the headernav, the footernav, etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To solve this problem, I did several things:**

1. I removed vm as a pattern, I cannot see any value in using it so I reverted back to the prior pattern of $scope.
2. Although the parent controller's function changeView is now accessible to the child [again, once ALL 'vm' is replaced with $scope in the project, I opted for $emit] :

---

**1. Index.html**

```
<body data-ng-controller ="RouteCtrl">       
    <div data-header=""></div> 
    <div data-ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">            
        <div data-side-bar=""></div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
 ......
 </body>
```

**2. Sidebar.html**

```
 < a style="cursor: pointer;" data-ng-click="handleNav(subItem.module,subItem.url)">{{subItem.name}}</a>
```

**3. Side Crtl:**

```
        $scope.handleNav = function (args1, args2) {
           $scope.$emit('handleNewView', (args1, args2));
         };
```

**4. Parent Crtl:**

```
    $scope.$on('handleNewView', function (args1, args2) {
        $scope.changeView(args1, args2);
      });

    $scope.changeView = function (moduleView, dashboardView) {
        $rootScope.event = { viewUrl: dashboardView, moduleUrl: moduleView };
        $location.path(dashboardView);
    };
```

**In conclusion, I cannot see any value in adopting "Controller as vm" as a pattern.**